# SQL Select column as substring at first occurrence of characters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using Postgresql and I need to run a query where I do a `SELECT DISTINCT` on a single string column. However I don't want to select the column as is, I need to substring it on the first occurrence of this string ' ('.

I do not know how to do this substring part..

Here is an example of the query without the substring part:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Table.Column1) Table.Column2 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY Table.Column1
```

I am not sure what functions to use in postgres or possibly I need to use plpgsql to do this?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous in at least two ways. `DISTINCT` before of after you extract the substring? And the definition of the substring is unclear. There is probably a more suitable function than `split_part()` for this. As *always*, also add your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work this out. The function to be used is SPLIT_PART. Which takes three parameters ColumnName, Characters, And the substring occurance.

Here is an example of how I have used it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (SPLIT_PART(Table.Column1, ' )', 1)) Table.Column2 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY SPLIT_PART(Table.Column1, ' )', 1)
```